# How to change database from Single user mode to multi user

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration, administrator

I have a Database,Which is in Single user mode ,If i want to access a tables in the database i   will be changing in the properties from single to multiuser.How can i make the Database multi user permenantly?.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET MULTI_USER`

If it throws an error like `user is already connected to it`, select 'master' db in the dropdown and try it that way.

If that doesn't do it, use `sp_who` to find what spid is accessing the DB and kill it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in SSMS object explorer.

Right click on your database.
Go to properties > options.
Scroll to the bottom and find "Restrict Access" and change it to multi_user.
Click ok.

Just an alternative to query window. Both do the same the same.

Comment: But every day morning it is going back to single User mode.Is there any way i can do it permenantly.

Comment: @SqlLearner Is the database being restored daily? Maybe there is a job that alters the database? Something is changing it back to single. I've had an instance where database properties appeared to change on their own and it ended up being a 3rd party script.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution.

I have the same error as you, I have tried all the ways but it doesn't work. Manually below I have restored to the original state of the database.

```
Step 1: Stop Sql Server Services
Step 2: Cut Data and Log file to other folder.
Step 3: Start Sql Server Services again.
Step 4: In SQL Studio Management -> Delete error database.
Step 5: Stop Sql Server Services and Copy Data to old folder.
Step 6: Attach again and auto change from single user to multi user
```

This solution test on Sql Server 2017 by me.